Can't connect to our own connector built using Google App Script
We build our own connector using Google App Script, but unfortunately We no longer connect to the connector like this

When I press 'REFRESH AUTHORISATION' button, it doesnt work, it just did nothing, the refresh button is also blurred out. please help what happened?
when I try to open the chart error, here is the error message

